# How could I remove some rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How could I remove some rows in dataframe

How could I to  keep `u'Lower End of Central Tendency'` and `u'Upper End of Central Tendency'` in the table. And remove the redundant rows ?

- The display table of dataframe (the content is from a JSON file)

[image]

- The **expected** table of dataframe (The marked rows is unnecessary)

[image]

- The JSON data is as below

  ```
  {u'2007': {u'Actual': u'3.5',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'-',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'-',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'-',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'-'},
   u'2008': {u'Actual': u'1.7',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'-',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'-',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'-',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'-'},
   u'2009': {u'Actual': u'1.4',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'-',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'-',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'-',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'-'},
   u'2010': {u'Actual': u'1.5',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'-',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'-',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'-',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'-'},
   u'2011': {u'Actual': u'2.5',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'-',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'-',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'-',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'-'},
   u'2012': {u'Actual': u'-',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'1.6',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'1.6',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'1.7',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'1.8'},
   u'2013': {u'Actual': u'-',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'1.3',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'1.3',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'2.0',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'2.0'},
   u'2014': {u'Actual': u'-',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'1.5',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'1.4',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'2.0',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'2.2'},
   u'2015': {u'Actual': u'-',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'1.7',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'1.5',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'2.0',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'2.2'},
   u'Longer Run': {u'Actual': u'-',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'2.0',
    u'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'2.0',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': u'2.0',
    u'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': u'2.0'}}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `drop()` function, and there are 2 ways to drop rows, by name and by index. It's probably easiest to show by example:

```
>>> df
       c1  c2  c3
one     0   1   2
two     3   4   5
three   6   7   8
four    9  10  11
>>> df2 = df.copy()
>>> df2.drop(['one', 'three'], axis=0, inplace=True)
>>> df2
      c1  c2  c3
two    3   4   5
four   9  10  11
```

Or you can drop rows using numerical indices of the index like this:

```
>>> df3.drop(df3.index[[0,3]], inplace=True)
>>> df3
       c1  c2  c3
two     3   4   5
three   6   7   8
```

The axis defaults to 0, so if you don't put it in, you're deleting rows. To delete columns, you use axis=1. The `inplace` parameter defaults to `False`. So if you just want a copy without the bad rows, leave that parameter out and save the return value.

Documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

Answer (score 0):

No need to drop just select the rows you're interested in:

```
df.loc[['Lower End of Central Tendency','Upper End of Central Tendency']]
```

will perform row label selection of just those rows, example:

```
In [164]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(5)})
df
Out[164]:
          a
0  0.523139
1  1.042023
2  1.528064
3 -1.920597
4 -0.408413
In [166]:

df.loc[[1,3]]
Out[166]:
          a
1  1.042023
```

**EDIT**

if you really want to remove them just assign it back to your df:

```
df = df.loc[[1,3]]
```

Comment: You can do that, too, which then provides a reference to the relevant rows only, but it doesn't "remove" them, as the OP asked. Whether you really want to *remove* them or just get a view that doesn't include them would depend on context.